# Empty table with readtable

Tags: matlab

I've got a .txt file that contains an header of 3 rows and then numbers:

```
#header1
#"Column 1" "Column 2"
#-------------
1 2
3 4
5 6
```

etc...repeated 100 times.

I tried with `readtable('data.txt')` but gives me a 0x2 table. Otherwise, removing all the 100 set of data, maintaining just the first one, it works perfectly.
How can I solve it? I don't understand what is wrong.

The final result that I'd like to have is 100 matrices Nx2 with all the set of data separated.

```
#Parameters
#"Time" "P1"
#----------------------------------
0.0000000000000    0.038352422909548
2.0000000000000e-05 0.21496038732289
4.0000000000000e-05 0.39105014651845
8.0000000000000e-05 0.74162500485882
0.00016000000000000 1.4364463117856
0.00032000000000000 2.8015165008700
#Parameters 
#"Time / us" "P1"
#------------------------------------
0.0000000000000    3.7048864099468
8.0000000000000e-05 4.7285658478510
0.00016000000000000 5.7312518603670
0.00032000000000000 7.6741377874436
0.00064000000000000 11.315025403325
0.0012800000000000 17.656293877689
```

Comment: R2021b and I cannot install the newest one

Comment: That's OK, I'm asking because the default behaviour of `readtable` changed a little bit in R2020a (per the [docs](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/readtable.html)). Looks like you could use `readtable( 'blah.txt', 'NumHeaderLines', 3, 'ReadVariableNames', false );` and fix the variable names later as one option

Comment: Still 0x26 empty table

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve], because if I save the text you've provided into `blah.txt` and run the exact code I've written above then it produces a 3x2 table with the expected contents. I'm unable to reproduce your issue.

Comment: Try to save the data as txt. If I remove the second set of measurements, I get the correct 6x2 table. With the two sets, a 0x3 table.

Comment: Your edited question is pretty different to your original and completely changes the possible solution. You may have to use `fgel` and parse the files manually, there are existing questions here about that

Comment: Actually, I just saved the .txt to .csv and using again `readtable` imports correctly the entire dataset. I just need to separe it now, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

[This example](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/import_export/import-block-of-mixed-data-from-text-file.html) shows how to import from text file multiple tables appended in similar way as the one shown in this question.

While this solution assumes you can tell in advance the exact position of all break lines between adjacent tables precisely, if such is not the case you may want to consider just importing the whole text file with command `textscan` and then process the file accordingly to generate 1 matrix per table, for instance catching each table from the Python `#` comment characters that seem to be always at the beginning of any comment line and only used in-between tables.